# Как правильно сделать, чтобы передавалось значения с массива на удаление

Tags: массивы, php, sql, mysql

```
<?
    echo "<table class='ram'><td>фио преп<td>должность
        <td>степень<td>контакт<td><form action=' ' method='post'>
        <input type='submit' name='delteacher' 
        value='Удалить выбранное'>";
    $t=("SELECT * FROM `преподаватели`");
$q=mysql_query($t)or die(mysql_error());  
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q);
        do
        {
        echo  "<tr><td>".$r['фио преподавателя']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$r['должность' ]."</td>";
        echo  "<td>".$r['степень']."</td>";
        echo  "<td>".$r['контакт преподавателя']."</td>".
        "<td>";
        ?><input type='checkbox' name='delt[]' 
        value=" <? $r['фио преподавателя'] ?>">

        <?
        }
        while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q));
        echo "</table></form>";
if(isset($_POST['delteacher']))
{
$mass=$_POST["delt"];
 $sel=("DELETE FROM `преподаватели` 
  WHERE `фио преподавателя`=$mass");
  }

    ?>
```

> if(isset($_POST['delteacher'])) {
> $mass=$_POST["delt"];  $sel=("DELETE
> FROM `преподаватели`    WHERE `фио
> преподавателя`=$mass");   }

или тут ошибся?

```
 <input type='checkbox' name='delt[]' 
            value=" <? $r['фио преподавателя'] ?>">
```

или?паникааа=(

Comment: можно `IN` в `MySQL` использовать и `implode` в `php` http://www.php.su/implode.

Comment: название таблиц и полей в русском формате глаза режет.. к тому же код отформатируете, чтобы он был более читаемым

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type='checkbox' name='delt[]' 
            value=" <? $r['фио преподавателя'] ?>">
```

Естесно, сначала выводите `<? print $r['фио преподавателя'] ?>`

И потом, delt[] - у вас массив, так что $mass собирайте с помощью [implode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php), и в запросе удалений пользуйтесь [in](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Comment: А можно поподробнее пожалуйста?